# Zend Studio 9: Remote Server and dot folders

Tags: eclipse, file, zend-framework, hidden, zend-studio

It looks like Zend Studio 9 "Remote Server Support" tool just ignores folders, beginning with a dot. And I hadn't found I it's possible to change this behavior.

---

**Example:**

1. Suppose we've got the following set of files on a local Win7 x64 machine:

   ```
   a/
    b/
     b_file1
     .c1/
        c_file1
   ```
2. Create a "PHP Project from existing directory"  (directory = "a")
3. Set up the connection (in Project properties -> Remote Server Support)
4. Agree to upload data to the server.

**Results:**

- b_file1 is uploaded OK.
- c_file1 and .c1 are missing.
- moreover(bonus): if one create a/b/.c2 folder, it would be uploaded, but a/b/.c2/c2_file would not.

**Question:**

How do I upload c_file and .c1 folder too?

PS:

Just in case my description wasn't accurate enough, [here's](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lT1TH2VQS1g) 3.5 minutes long screenvideo (exactly the same as "Example" above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a couple of ways to sync this folders anyway, regardless of "Remote Server Support"

1. [Here's](http://kb.zend.com/index.php?View=entry&EntryID=414) an official Zend's article on how to do this with rsync
2. [Here's](http://i3vi3v.wordpress.com/2013/01/09/zend-studio-syncing-files-with-remote-server-using-unison/) a tutorial on how to use another, more advanced external tool - unison, which can be "integrated" too.